# Multiple Data Sources For Single TableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, twitter, facebook-ios-sdk

I am making requests to obtain searched posts from both Facebook and Twitter, using the integrated APIs. What I want to do is to combine the data from both Facebook and Twitter into a single table view, organised by date.

I could do this in PHP and then make a single request to that PHP script, however that's slightly difficult due to the required authentication and that's annoying to have to pass over to the script, I would rather do it in app.

So basically, how would I go about combining data from multiple locations into a single UITableView?

Answer (score 0):

Decide on an internal data representation, this could be a custom class or a dictionary with a set of keys. When you receive data from FB or TW you want to map the data into your common internal format and the add the instances to an array (existing if you have already received some data or new if not). Now you have a common list of data you can sort that list by date and show it in the table view. You can add an identifier to the instances too if you want so you know where the data originated (so you can display or handle it differently).

If you wanted to use different sections in the table view then just have 2 different arrays (and you wouldn't need the common data format, but it would probably make life easier).